# Optimize the reuse of MySql subquery

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I have this query that does what I need, however I feel I can improve it a bit but I'm unsure how.

```
SELECT * 
     (CASE WHEN (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond1 ORDER BY o1 LIMIT 1) then 'something0'
           WHEN (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond2 ORDER BY o2 LIMIT 1) then 'something1'
           WHEN (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond3 ORDER BY o3 LIMIT 1) then 'something2'
           WHEN (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond4 ORDER BY o4 LIMIT 1) then 'something3'
           WHEN (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond5 ORDER BY o5 LIMIT 1) then 'something4'
      END) as columnX
      FROM tbl1
      WHERE another_cond1 AND f1 = (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond1 ORDER BY o1 LIMIT 1)
         OR another_cond2 AND f1 = (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond2 ORDER BY o2 LIMIT 1)
         OR another_cond3 AND f1 = (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond3 ORDER BY o3 LIMIT 1)
         OR another_cond4 AND f1 = (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond4 ORDER BY o4 LIMIT 1)
         OR another_cond5 AND f1 = (SELECT f1 FROM tbl1 WHERE cond5 ORDER BY o5 LIMIT 1)
```

I tried to use variables but without much success, especially after reading MySQL documentation, which says 'As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement'.

Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried with JOINS, and with LEFT JOINS won't work because the queries might not return any results. With the FULL OUTER JOIN emulation it just takes too long. (Tested on a table with ~5000 rows)

Answer (score 1):

why not just do unions... yes it may be a little longer, but SHOULD be more efficient. Your query is querying from tbl1 not just in the where, but in the where condition, and again in the field condition.  Select the criteria ONCE per SELECT ONCE and union that with all 5 different criteria / sets / order by conditions

```
select f1 as ColumnX
   from tbl1
   where another_cond1 and cond1
   order by o1
   limit 1
UNION ALL
select f1 as ColumnX
   from tbl1
   where another_cond2 and cond2
   order by o2
   limit 1
UNION ALL
select f1 as ColumnX
   from tbl1
   where another_cond3 and cond3
   order by o3
   limit 1
UNION ALL
select f1 as ColumnX
   from tbl1
   where another_cond4 and cond4
   order by o4
   limit 1
UNION ALL
select f1 as ColumnX
   from tbl1
   where another_cond5 and cond5
   order by o5
   limit 1
```

Comment: That would work if I didn't want to add the 'something' to ColumnX if the query has a result. CASE WHEN query1 THEN "something" WHEN query2 THEN "somethingElse".